# .Net WinForms application: Form flickers when changing Form.ShowInTaskbar value

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Consider the following code:

```
Me.ShowInTaskbar = Not ShowInTaskbar
```

Everytime I call this line of code, the form flickers for a small period of time (probably depends on how many controls are on the form).

**Okay, why do I want to run this in the first place?**

Basically, I have a main form which I use to show some dialog forms and I want to be able to minimize/restore both forms (main & dialog) by a single click on the taskbar , so I'm using this code:

```
    Dim dialogForm As New frmDialog
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    dialogForm.ShowDialog(Me)
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
```

And *in the dialog form*:

```
Private Sub frmDialog_Resize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    frmMain.Visible = Me.WindowState <> FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub
```

Now, everything works fine **except** that the form flickers every time I enable/disable the `ShowInTaskbar` property (this is very critical to me as it would affect every dialog form I have).

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? **or** is there any other way to handle the minimizing/restoring thingy without touching the `ShowInTaskbar` property?

(I found some topics discussing this but I couldn't find any useful solution).

**Note:** *I don't want to hide the main form or make it clickable*.

Comment: Unrelated but Why checking on Resize event? You have a specific one for window state changes

Comment: A specific event for that? Which is?!

Comment: Windows will send WM_SYSCOMMAND to your form when window state changes, override WndPrc and check for that command with wParam for SC_MINIMIZE, SC_MAXIMIZE and SC_RESTORE.

Comment: You are creating an instance (dialogForm) of frmDialog that you are not using, correct? Perhaps you are seeing the result of two instances of it.

Comment: @user34660 No it was just a mistake in this example (this is not the case in the original code), I've edited it anyways.. thanks for the note :)

Comment: You could try setting the Form's DoubleBuffered property to True in the Form designer.

Comment: @DavidWilson Still flickers!

Comment: Do you know of an application that behaves the way you want yours to? Most Microsoft applications, such as VS, do not "minimize/restore both forms (main & dialog) by a single click on the taskbar". If you find an application that works the way you want yours to then perhaps we can determine how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code in your form -

```
Private originalExStyle As Integer = -1
Private enableFormLevelDoubleBuffering As Boolean = True

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        If originalExStyle = -1 Then
            originalExStyle = MyBase.CreateParams.ExStyle
        End If

        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams

        If enableFormLevelDoubleBuffering Then
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000
        Else
            ' WS_EX_COMPOSITED

            cp.ExStyle = originalExStyle
        End If
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
```

Please find more details here - http://www.angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2010/07/21/how-to-get-rid-of-flicker-on-windows-forms-applications.aspx

Comment: I added both the override property, and the `TurnOffFormLevelDoubleBuffering` method, and called that method on `Form_Shown` event as described in the article. Unfortunately it still flickers!